# Lookup OnChange event doesn't fire on hitting delete key

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-2013

Lookup OnChange event doesn't fire on hitting delete key to remove the lookup value. However, on changing lookup content (name) using keyboard it does fire.

Is this any bug or is by default?
How to trigger the OnChange event in this case?

Comment: It doesn't fire when tabbing off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will trigger when the control loses focus. So when you tab out of the lookup control, or click somewhere else in the form the event is fired. When you change the value in the lookup, except deleting, it will trigger right away.

Comment: oops.. there was some js code that was interrupting my logic and hence was mimicking like the OnChange didn't fire.